# Calculating number of times a given element appears in powerset subsets of a particular size.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, binomial-theorem

Let $X$ be a finite set, and $P(X)$ the power set of $X$. I understand from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Relation_to_binomial_theorem) how to calculate the number of subsets of a particular size in $P(X)$. For a given member of $X$ (call it $n$) how can I calculate the number of times $n$ appears in a set of subsets of a given size?

For example, suppose $X = \{1, 2, 3\}$ and $n = 2$. Then the subsets of $P(X)$ with two members are $\{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}$ and $\{2, 3\}$. $n$ is in two thirds of these. But is there a more general way for determining the number of times $n$ appears in a subset of $P(X)$ containing only sets of identical size?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**- Let the size of the desired subsets be $k$ and the total size of the set $N$. So you want the number of $k$-subsets of the set which have a particular element $n$. Now let's assume element $n$ is present in a subset. That leaves $k-1$ elements inside the subset that have to be filled from the remaining $N-1$. The number of ways to select $k-1$ elements from a group of $N-1$ is  ....

**EDIT**- Since the OP insisted, I'm giving out the answer

$$\binom{N-1}{k-1}$$

Comment: I really appreciate your response. I'm afraid you will have to spell out the answer for me though --- sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $X$ has $N$ elements. The probability that a particular element (you call it $n$) is in a randomly chosen 
subset of size $k$ is just $k/N$.

So if there are $M$ subsets of size $k$ the number of them that contain $n$ is $(k/N)M$.

Since you say you know how to calculate $M$ you're done.

Comment: Thanks so much, really appreciate this. 

I've just realised that I slightly misstated my question, which was in fact:

If $n \subseteq X$, how many members of the set of k-sized subsets (e.g. the set $\{k_1, k_2 ...\}$ are such that $n \subseteq$ those members? 

You seem like a much more experienced stack user than me -- should I edit my existing question or am I supposed to add a new one fresh?

Comment: @burt_gellorbsen Normally I'd suggest accepting an answer to this one and asking a new correct one. In this case you might be able to work out the probability in the first paragraph of my answer for your modified question, then continue as in the rest of the answer.